nvcc - add flags to a specific file using cmake
I am writing a CXX+CUDA project, and I'm compiling using nvcc, with CXX compiler of icpc.
I want to add different compilation flags for icpc for different files. In CXX standalone this is possible using set_source_files_properties() method, but I tried it in my case and it didn't work.
Minimal example for my structure -
cat main.cu
#include "file1.cuh"
#include "file2.cuh"

int main() {

    int3 size = make_int3(1, 1, 1);
    std::cout << size.x << std::endl;
    print_x<<<1,1>>>(size);
    print_y<<<1,1>>>(size);
    return 0;
}

cat file1.cuh
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void print_x(int3 arr);

cat file1.cu
#include "file1.cuh"
#include <iostream>

__global__ void print_x(int3 arr) { printf("%d", arr.x); }

cat file2.cuh
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void print_y(int3 arr);

cat file2.cu
#include "file2.cuh"

__global__ void print_y(int3 arr) { printf("%d", arr.y); }

cat CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "icc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icpc")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "nvcc")
project(proj LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(COMMON_CC_COMPILER_FLAGS -std=c++17 -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wall -lstdc++fs)
set(COMMON_FLAGS ${COMMON_CC_COMPILER_FLAGS})
string(JOIN ", " COMMON_FLAGS_FOR_CUDA_CC_COMPILER "${COMMON_CC_COMPILER_FLAGS}")
string(REPLACE ";" "," COMMON_FLAGS_FOR_CUDA_CC_COMPILER "${COMMON_FLAGS_FOR_CUDA_CC_COMPILER}")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)
set(COMMON_FLAGS_CUDA -ccbin=icpc --compiler-options "${COMMON_FLAGS_FOR_CUDA_CC_COMPILER}")
string(REPLACE ";" " " FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS}")
list(APPEND COMMON_FLAGS -DFLAGS="${FLAGS}")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

add_executable(proj main.cu file1.cu file2.cu)
target_compile_options(proj PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${COMMON_FLAGS}> $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:${COMMON_FLAGS_CUDA}>)

When compiling this project, the flags under --compiler-options indeed pass correctly to icpc, but I want different flags for each source. For example, I would like file1.cu to also be compiled with -pedantic -Werror.
I'm trying to do this by adding:
set_source_files_properties(
    file1.cu
    PROPERTIES 
    COMPILE_FLAGS "--compiler-options -Wall")

to the CMakeLists.txt file, but I see no change in the compilation command applied for this file (I checked using VERBOSE=1 make). I tried several other variations after PROPERTIES, but none of them work.
How can I get different additional compilation flags to apply to different files?

Note:  that I want the compilation to be done automatically using CMake since I have a large project with many components, so usage of CUDA_COMPILE method is not relevant in my state. I'm looking for some parallel method to set_source_files_properties() which is applicable in my scope.

I am using icpc 2021.4, nvcc 12.2, and cmake 3.21.4.

COMPILE_FLAGS was superseded by COMPILE_OPTIONS but I don't think that that is the cause.

target_compile_features(proj PRIVATE cxx_std_17 cuda_std_17) is the preferred way of specifying the (minimal) required standard(s) at target scope (I don't know if you need this at source file scope as well). Also note that CMake can in theory decide to use a higher standard because this just specifies the minimum. Also CMake generally allows compiler extensions (i.e. it uses -std=gnu++17 with g++ if you let it), so I usually have set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) before project() to avoid that.

-lstdc++fs is a linker flag. It should not be part of the compiler options. Instead use target_link_libraries(proj PRIVATE stdc++fs).

include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}) should not be necessary either. As the docs mention it might (only) be useful when compiling .cpp files that use some CUDA API. Even for that case there is a cleaner way using find_package(CUDAToolkit) and linking the targets it provides.

@paleonix Thanks a lot for all of the insights! I will try as much as I can to apply them to my code (my actual project is of course much more complicated).
Unfortunately, my code relies heavily on .cu files doing host operations as well, which needs to be compiled with specific C++ flags. The static analysis was actually just for the sake of example, and the actual flags I need are different (and relate to CPU specific architecture).
Just to make sure I understood you correctly, there is no work-around for my issue? (i.e., generating to different nvcc command for different files)

You could try doing this at the target level and have different targets for different source files. I.e. create static libraries from file1.cu and file2.cu that are then linked to the executable target.

Interesting idea, I'll give it a shot and see if I can work something out.

@paleonix - Your solution seem to work, and actually makes sense "compilewise" (having separate targets for CPU, GPU, and "generic" files - each is compiled in a different setup. The linking seem also quite smooth. Thanks!

Does this happen with GCC as opposed to ICPC?

It's problem with your CMakeLists files + flags combination
I just built a project similar to yours (more of an MWE...) with CMake 3.28.3, and did not experience this problem.
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "nvcc")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "icpc")
project(my_proj LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_library(my_proj foo.cu bar.cu)
set_source_files_properties(foo.cu
    PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "--compiler-options -Wunused-parameter")

foo.cu:
int foo(int x) { return (100 > 1) == 3; }

bar.cu:
int bar(int x) { return (100 > 1) == 3; }

and this is what the build looks like:
$ cmake --build build
[2/3] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/my_proj.dir/foo.cu.o
/tmp/delme/foo.cu: In function ‘int foo(int)’:
/tmp/delme/foo.cu:1:13: warning: unused parameter ‘x’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int foo(int x) { return (100 > 1) == 3; }
         ~~~~^
[3/3] Linking CUDA static library libmy_proj.a

so, one compilation and one linking had no issues, and one compilation complained about the unused parameter - just as expected.
... but you can always wrap file compilations with object library targets.
Let's suppose that you have four files:

main.cu can be compiled with no special flags for the host-side code
file1.cu needs to be compiled with flag -O1 for the host-side code
file2.cu and file3.cu need to be compiled with flag -Ofast for the host-side code.

Now, use an "object library target" for each combination of compilation flags:
add_library(compiled_with_o1 OBJECT file1.cu)
add_library(compiled_with_ofast OBJECT file2.cu file3.cu)
add_executable(my_program main.cu) # no special wrapping for main.cu
target_link_libraries(my_program compiled_with_o1 compiled_with_ofast)

You can now use CMake's per-target compilation options setting command, like so:
target_compile_options(compiled_with_o1 PRIVATE "--compiler-options -O1")
target_compile_options(compiled_with_ofast PRIVATE "--compiler-options -Ofast")


Notes: The second approach is the same basic idea as @paleonix' answer, but with OBJECT libraries.

I had in the back of my had that the last time I tried using object libraries in CMake with CUDA it didn't work, so I didn't mention them. But I haven't tested again so if this works it is (slightly) better than static libraries because it avoids putting the object files into an archive.

I agree, worked fine for me with the object libraries.

@paleonix: Actually, both our approaches are irrelevant, because set_source_files_properties works fine with ICPC and NVCC, so amended my answer.

I actually think the target approach is cleaner.

@Amit: 1. It introduces artificial entities. 2. If you can verify that set_source_files_properties() works, I believe you should either change the accepted answer, or at least edit the question somewhat.

I will re-verify that in both my toy project and my actual code

Updating that thanks to @einpoklum I found the issue in my original CMakeLists, and set_source_file_properties actually works in this framework. So my question was basically redundant, but I'd still keep the solution you both suggested with the additional targets, honestly I think it's cleaner. Thanks for all the help!

@Amit could you share what caused the issue for you?

Edit: While I was sure I reproduced the problem of COMPILE_FLAGS on CUDA source files being ignored, I can't reproduce it anymore. I.e. I must have introduced some kind of problem myself the first time and I can't figure out how (neither with GGC as the host compiler nor with ICPC).

The easiest workaround (and maybe even the better strategy and style independent of this particular problem) is to have a CMake target (e.g. a static library) for each file or group of files that needs different compiler options. The target-level APIs for setting compiler options work without a problem and are more elegant to use (avoiding explicit property names like COMPILE_OPTIONS in favor of CMake function names like target_compile_options(), target_compile_features(), etc. with easy specification of PRIVATE vs PUBLIC).
All these targets can then be linked to the executable target in the end using target_link_libraries().
